# How can I tell if GNU GSL is installed?

Tags: software-installation, osx, gnu, shared-library

How can I find out if GNU Scientific Library is installed?

OSX 10.11

Answer (score 3):

Apple doesn't install it (afaik), so you'll need Fink or MacPorts or homebrew or a manual install. Assuming a properly configured `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` for Fink or MacPorts or homebrew or the manual install, in this case MacPorts, `pkg-config` might indicate the presence of `gsl` (and, bonus, the various compiler flags to use).

```
% echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH 
/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig
% pkg-config --cflags --libs gsl
-I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
%
```